# Writing DataFrame as parquet creates empty files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera, parquet, apache-spark-2.3

I am trying to do some performance optimization for Spark job using **bucketing** technique. I am reading `.parquet` and `.csv` files and do some transformations. After I am doing bucketing and join two DataFrames. Then I am writing joined DF to parquet but I have an empty file of `~500B` instead of `500Mb`.

- Cloudera (cdh5.15.1)
- Spark 2.3.0
- Blob

  ```
  val readParquet = spark.read.parquet(inputP)
  readParquet
      .write
      .format("parquet")
      .bucketBy(23, "column")
      .sortBy("column")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .saveAsTable("bucketedTable1")

  val firstTableDF = spark.table("bucketedTable1")

  val readCSV = spark.read.csv(inputCSV)
  readCSV
      .filter(..)
      .ordrerBy(someColumn)

      .write
      .format("parquet")
      .bucketBy(23, "column")
      .sortBy("column")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .saveAsTable("bucketedTable2")

  val secondTableDF = spark.table("bucketedTable2")

  val resultDF = secondTableDF
      .join(firstTableDF, Seq("column"), "fullouter")
      .
      .
  resultDF
      .coalesce(1)
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .parquet(output)
  ```

When I launch Spark job in command line using `ssh` I have correct result, `~500Mb` parquet file which I can see using Hive. If I run the same job using oozie workflow I have an empty file (`~500 Bytes`).
When I do `.show()` on my `resultDF` I can see the data but I have empty parquet file.

```
+-----------+---------------+----------+
|       col1|          col2 |      col3|
+-----------+---------------+----------+
|33601234567|208012345678910|       LOL|
|33601234567|208012345678910|       LOL|
|33601234567|208012345678910|       LOL|
```

There is no problem writing to parquet when I am not saving data as a table. It occurs only with DF created from table.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

Comment: empty file has  _SUCCESS along with it ?

Comment: forget about existing dataframe write this dataframe via oozie in the same flow before you write existing problematic parquet like this `spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 4).toDF
      .coalesce(1)
      .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(destDir)` see what happens and dont think this is spark issue. it might be some other issue

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Yes there is _SUCCESS file with it. Without bucketing and ```.saveAsTable()``` it works good, I've just tried to avoid Shuffle problem.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram And your suggestion with ```spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 4).toDF .coalesce(1) .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(destDir)``` works with Oozie. I can query the data in table.

Comment: Seq("coumn"), might be Seq("column") i consider this as type remaining everthing look good for me

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram No. Even when I am saving a single DF to a table without `.bucketBy` and `.sortBy` there is the same problem. It can't read from table.

Comment: can you do msck repair on table?

Comment: Bucketing is enabled by default. Spark SQL uses `spark.sql.sources.bucketing.enabled configuration` property to control whether bucketing should be enabled and used for query optimization or not. can  you check this property ?

Comment: can reffer this https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-bucketing.html which is same as what you are doing... but Bucketing is not supported for `DataFrameWriter.save`, `DataFrameWriter.insertInto` and `DataFrameWriter.jdbc` methods.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Bucketing is enabled I can verify it in SparkHistory. I am using the page of @jaceklaskowski  and for `.saveAsTable()` bucketing is supported. It's even work when I launch Spark job in command line but not in Oozie wf.

Comment: i hope sprak 2.3 onwards bucketing was supported. please verify oozie libraries are correct version of spark 2.3. this is the last suggestion i can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out for my case I just added an option `.option("path", "/sources/tmp_files_path")`. Now I can use bucketing and I have a data in my output files.

```
readParquet
  .write
  .option("path", "/sources/tmp_files_path")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .bucketBy(23, "column")
  .sortBy("column")
  .saveAsTable("bucketedTable1")
```